# Unaccounted for electoral votes

Tags: united-states, election, electoral-college, faithless-elector

All the electoral college votes trackers on the different websites are reporting that Trump has 290, and Clinton has 228. Where are the unaccounted for 20 votes? Are they all faithless electors, or have they just yet to cast their ballot?

Answer (score 7):

New Hampshire (4) and Michigan (16) were both late in confirming their totals.  Canvassing in both states need to occur

On Nov 11, MI confirmed for President Trump.  See link below.

NH remains a tight contest with about 2600 vote difference in favor of Clinton.  The AP which calls most races, still hasn't called it, although CNN, and NH papers have declared Clinton the victor.  [Link](http://heavy.com/news/2016/11/michigan-new-hampshire-arizona-election-results-2016-called-calls-ap-cnn-have-they-been-called-why-havent-returns-votes-recount-trump-clinton-hillary-wisconsin/)  After canvassing, NH could be required by its own laws for a mandatory recount.

The electors in the Electoral College don't vote until Dec 19 [Link](http://www.ibtimes.com/can-hillary-clinton-still-win-electoral-college-vote-december-after-candidate-wins-2445319)

Comment: Which should be noted even if both went her way it would not change the election outcome. In either case Trump still wins the electoral college vote and will be president. The can of worms that would be opened if enough electors didn't follow their state votes to cause Trump to lose at this point...well lets hope we don't see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Associated Press reports:

Trump:   290 Electoral Votes 60,834,437 popular votes (47.16%)

Hillary: 232 Electoral Votes 61,782,016 popular votes (47.89%)

Hillary received 947,579 more votes than Trump as of 20:56 11-16-16.

http://www.wral.com/news/political/page/16162630/?group=top_races

Comment: How does that answer the question?